# How to print directly from printer with Yii?

Tags: php, printing, yii, network-printers

How do I print directly from printer?

This is a intranet web application. The user will use this application and they will print out the report from the printer of their department (different department, different printer). I'm Googling to print out directly from printer, but I can't find anywhere. I'm using Yii Framework 1.11.

How can I do this? Is it possible to print out directly from printer? How?

Comment: it's possible by adding this to your view `<script>window.print();</script>` is that an option?, and as a side note: what else can you directly print from other than a printer :)

Comment: yes window.print will print the whole web page. now, the client want to print out only report by .xls(csv) or pdf. but they do not want to allow to save to employee pc, just only print.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$fhandle = fopen("test.php","rb");
$contents = fread($fhandle, filesize("test.php"));
$output = eval($contents);

$handle = printer_open("Dell Laser Printer M5200");
printer_set_option($handle,PRINTER_MODE,"raw");
printer_write($handle,$output);
printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: The printer should not be define. there are different departments have different printers.(1 department has 2 printer, at least.) one of the printers may be replace by other brand new printer while it was damage.

Answer (score 0):

For web application all print works has dependency with your browser. You have to create a page or popup window just for print view with special Html and css.

Comment: what does you mean special HTML and CSS?

Comment: Can you help me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

AT least I fount the best way. I got the js from following site.

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/printing-web-pages-a-new-jquery-printing-plugin/

My View (index or something)

```
    <p align="right">
        <?php 

            echo CHtml::link('New Job',array('create'),array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));
            echo CHtml::link('Print',array('print'),array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-info', 'style'=>'margin-left: 10px;'));
        ?>
    </p>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$jobs->search(),
    'filter'=>$jobs,
...)); ?>
```

My Controller

```
public function actionPrint() {
        $d = $_SESSION['all'];
        $this->renderPartial('print',array('d'=>$d),false,true);
}
```

My model

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
        $criteria->compare('department_id',$this->department_id);
        $criteria->compare('section_id',$this->section_id);
        $criteria->compare('team_id',$this->team_id);
        $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('updated_date',$this->updated_date,true);

        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>false,
        ));
        $_SESSION['all'] = $data;

        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                        Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
        $_SESSION['limited'] = $data;

        return $data;
    }
```

My view (print.php)

```
<div id="summary">
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Job No.</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>  
    <?php   
    $i=1;
    foreach($d->data as $item)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentsdep->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentssec->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentstea->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: i get an error of Undefined index: all. Why is it so?

Comment: @ Femme Fatale, above answer is not my code but it I look at that code and see your question. I think error comes from this line of code  $_SESSION['all']. I think because you did not set the session with the parameter 'all'.