# how to sort before printing in yii

Tags: sorting, yii, printing

so I found this:
[How to print directly from printer with Yii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988444/how-to-print-directly-from-printer-with-yii)

and the 2nd answer (the one with the jquery) was the one I felt was most suitable for me
but I just want to know, is there a way I can sort these out before printing? like for example In the model

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
    $criteria->compare('department_id',$this->department_id);
    $criteria->compare('section_id',$this->section_id);
    $criteria->compare('team_id',$this->team_id);
    $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('updated_date',$this->updated_date,true);

    $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>false,
    ));
    $_SESSION['all'] = $data;

    $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                    Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
    $_SESSION['limited'] = $data;

    return $data;
}
```

is it possible to display this ordered by the name maybe or the date instead of just the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
  'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',
  )
));
```